# Логотип = емблема?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=26065&page=873) пише, що:

> 1) **ЕМБЛЕ́МА**, и, ж.Умовне, ***символічне*** ***зображення*** якого-небудь поняття, ідеї.
>
> З балконів звисали зелені прапори з білим голубом – емблемою миру (П. Тичина).
>
> 2) **ЛОГОТИ́П**, а, ч. Спеціально розроблений ***знак*** (оригінальне поєднання зображень, літер, цифр і слів), що передає повне або скорочене найменування установи, організації, фірми і т. ін.
>
> Попiльничка з логотипом фiрми, якiй належала газета, стояла на столi постiйно (А. Кокотюха).

І це, і це символ, що передає основну інформацію про щось. Наприклад, в айфоні яблучко - це логотип чи емблема? Якщо враховувати, що символ айфона - це яблуко, тоді це емблема, якщо ж яблуко - це знак / позначення, тоді це логотип. Можливо у тому випадку яблучко - це водночас і логотип, і емблема?

Отже, що є що? І чим відрізнаються ці поняття?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У статті [Чим відрізняється логотип від емблеми?](http://poradumo.com.ua/302451-c-288/) знаходимо:

> Головна відмінність логотипу від емблеми — в тому, що в першому рисунку основну площу картинки займає літерне найменування товару або бренду, у другому — абстрактне зображення, яке асоційоване з товаром або брендом.

Однак, дальше у статті йдеться про те, що емблему і логотип розрізнити важко. Поняття часто не розмежовуються. Таку ж інформацію знаходимо у [Розробка логотипів та фірмового стилю](http://mimino.ua/poslugi/rozrobka-logotipiv-ta-firmovogo-stilu)
 та  у [Визначення сутності логотипів та їх класифікація](https://naub.oa.edu.ua/2014/vyznachennya-sutnosti-lohotypiv-ta-jih-klasyfikatsiya/) .

Щодо «яблучка», то це логотип і пояснення цього, думаю, пов’язане з наступним [Чим відрізняється логотип від емблеми?](http://poradumo.com.ua/302451-c-288/#%D1%81_menu):

> ще один критерій розмежування розглядуваних понять — сфера застосування. Так, відносно графічних елементів, що мають відношення до символіки спортивних команд, досить рідко вживається термін «логотип». У свою чергу, якщо мова йде про відомий комерційний бренд, то навіть якщо він пізнається по зображенню, явно відповідного ознаками емблеми, дана картинка часто іменується логотипом.

П.С.  За формальними ознаками деякі "емблеми" спортивних команд, в принципі, можна віднести і до логотипу — але традиції іменувати «логотипами» ті емблеми, що використовуються спортивними командами, не склалося [Чим відрізняється логотип від емблеми?](http://poradumo.com.ua/302451-c-288/#%D1%81_menu)